# Android Clean Architecture double implement

Tags: java, android, clean-architecture

I am in the process of learning the Android clean architecture, and I am using this as an example https://github.com/dmilicic/Android-Clean-Boilerplate

I have created a class diagram of some of the code to better understand it, and then this hit me.
The  Interactor interface is "double" implemented, if I use the authors description of how to use the architecture. He says that every interactor created, should extend the AbstractInteractor, and also should implement a separate interface (in this case WelcomingInteractor, which also is extending the Interactor interface.

Is this just an error on the authors side. or is there a good reason for this?

Best Regards Morten

[image]

Comment: Why not ask the author? His email is up on [his profile](https://github.com/dmilicic).

Comment: It seems to me like the `WelcomingInteractor` is an unnecessary implementation here. It seems like you would want to pass an implementation of `WelcomingInteractor` into the class extending from `AbstractInteractor`. Then have execute call those functions in the passed in `WelcomingInteractor` implementation.